# android Hide the entire part of the side menu

Tags: android

I am a Beginner in Android.
I want to hide the text in the side menu.
But when I am doing that I am getting a space in that place.
When I pressed, that space it moves to another page
Is there any way that the whole part is hidden without being deleted?
The problem is if I delete that, it will require further modifications and deletion of other files
I just want to hide the text with its link
I tried a lot, but all attempts failed

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="@{build.isMobil?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}">

    <View
        android:background="@color/light_gray_color1"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="@{build.isMobil?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}" />

    <TextView
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="@{(v)->handlers.onClickProfile(v)}"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding"
        android:text="@string/title_page"
        android:textColor="@color/drawer_label"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="@{build.isMobil?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}" />

    <View
        android:background="@color/light_gray_color1"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="@{build.isMobil?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}" />

    <TextView
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="@{(v)->handlers.onClick()}"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:text="@string/become"
        android:textColor="@color/drawer_label"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="@{homedata.partner==0?(homedata.partnerApproveRequired?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE):View.GONE}" />

    <TextView
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_heading"
        android:text="@string/request_pending"
        android:textColor="@color/drawer_label"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="@{homedata.partner==0?(homedata.partnerApproveRequired?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE):View.GONE}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use

```
                            android:text=""
```

Comment: make the textview visibility to gone, so no modification will be required and it will not be visible on screen.

Comment: Yes, the text has disappeared
But when pressed, it goes to another page
Clicking on the link still works

Comment: then you need to remove hide the layout which has the click listener on it

Comment: i think when we make something gone, clicks are not possible then.

Comment: Unfortunately, when pressing is still working Here is the problem, I can not adjust more
I made an attempt before using code android:onClick="null" But it didn't work right

Comment: tha @PraveenSP how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have successfully hidden
By using this code

```
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
```

He is editing width and height

```
"0dp"
```